golang-fips cannot retrieve OpenSSL version
I'm trying to run a docker.io container in podman 4.9.4 that uses go1.22.5-3. I'm getting the error "openssl: can't retrieve OpenSSL version" when I try to "podman exec -it" to the container. It looks like the error is coming from init.go (code block below).
OpenSSL is installed (RHEL 8). What would cause dlopen to not be able to determine the major/minor/patch version of the installed OpenSSL?
// opensslInit loads and initialize OpenSSL.
// If successful, it returns the major and minor OpenSSL version
// as reported by the OpenSSL API.
//
// See Init() for details about file.
func opensslInit(file string) (major, minor, patch uint, err error) {
    // Load the OpenSSL shared library using dlopen.
    handle, err := dlopen(file)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, 0, 0, err
    }

    // Retrieve the loaded OpenSSL version and check if it is supported.
    // Notice that major and minor could not match with the version parameter
    // in case the name of the shared library file differs from the OpenSSL
    // version it contains.
    imajor := int(C.go_openssl_version_major(handle))
    iminor := int(C.go_openssl_version_minor(handle))
    ipatch := int(C.go_openssl_version_patch(handle))
    if imajor < 0 || iminor < 0 || ipatch < 0 {
        return 0, 0, 0, errors.New("openssl: can't retrieve OpenSSL version")
    }

sudo podman --log-level=debug run --name <name> -d <container>
sudo podman --log-level=debug exec -i <name> ls

debug output includes:
panic: opensslcrypto: can't initialize OpenSSL : openssl: can't retrieve OpenSSL version

goroutine 1 ... [running]:
panic({...})
   /usr/lib/goland/src/runtime/panic.go:779
crypto/internal/backend.init.0()
   /usr/lib/golang/src/crypto/internal/backend/openssl.go:65
runtime.doInit1(...)
   /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:7176
runtime.doInit(...)
   /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:7143
runtime.main()
   /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/proc.go:253
runtime.goexit({})
   /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695

...

time="..." level=error msg="exec failed:  unable to start container process: read init-p: connection reset by peer


It would be nice if Go told you which of those calls actually failed.  Because this code sure looks like it'd barf on OpenSSL v1.1.x: if (num < 0x10000000L || num >= 0x10200000L)

That might be it — I think we have OpenSSL 1.1.* installed
